# can i glob dirnames to an array and then usort by a file value?

Tags: php, glob, usort

Can anyone please advise whether I can write a function for `usort` that will do the following in PHP :

Firstly I have a bunch of directories that all have two files inside - these two files each contain a number as plain text

Here is what I want to do :

glob the list of directories into an array call `$dirs`

use a `usort` function to do the following :

1. Read the two files (file1.txt and file2.txt) in each directory and multiply them together to create a 3rd number called $value
2. Sort the original $dirs array into descending order by the $value for each dir.

Ok - I can glob the files like this:

```
$dirs = glob('*',GLOB_NOSORT|GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

and I can pull the values easily enough using `file_get_contents` but I can't figure out how to combine all of this into a function for `usort`.

Comment: You can use intval on the return value of file_get_contents provided they are integers. I think the examples at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php are not difficult to work with. Lastly, I hope this is an assignment, not a real-world "database".

Comment: Thanks for the help Adder - So, does usort call the function multiple times and would it be wasteful if there were hundreds of directories to filter through?  Would I be better looping through the first array returned by usort,  grabbing the values just once for each dir and adding it to another (multi-dimensional) array with the dirname and the value and the usorting that second array>

Comment: Yes, calculating the product first would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

$dirs = array();
foreach (glob('*',GLOB_NOSORT|GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir) {
    $value = 
        (int)file_get_contents($dir.'/file1.txt') * 
        (int)file_get_contents($dir.'/file2.txt') ;
    $dirs[] = array(
        'path'  => $dir,
        'value' => $value,
    );
}

usort($dirs, function($a, $b) {
    return $b['value'] - $a['value'];
});
```

Then you want to get one-dimensional result,

```
$dirs = array_map(function ($dir) {
    return $dir['path'];
}, $dirs);
```

Comment: Does just writing `$b['value'] - $a['value'];` return a value in PHP too, I'm just familar with that from other languages?

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet will do the trick:

```
$dirs = glob('*',GLOB_NOSORT|GLOB_ONLYDIR); 
usort($dirs, function ($a, $b) {
    $val_a = $val_b = 1;
    foreach(scandir($a) as $file) {
        if(strpos($file, '.') === 0) {
            continue;
        }   
        $val_a *= intval(trim(file_get_contents($a. '/' . $file)));
    }   
    foreach(scandir($b) as $file) {
        if(strpos($file, '.') === 0) {
            continue;
        }   
        $val_b *= intval(trim(file_get_contents($b. '/' . $file)));
    }   

    if($val_a === $val_b) {
        return 0;
    } else if($val_a > $val_b) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1; 
    }   
});

var_dump($dirs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using 5.3.0 or better, you can use an [anonymous function](http://php.net/functions.anonymous) to do this. Below you will see the function `buildSort`, which returns a function object (called by PHP a "closure", although it's heavily debated in some circles whether this term is being correctly applied.) We'll use this to "memoize" the reads of dir/file1.txt and dir/file2.txt, as well as the math operations, so we only need to perform those once per directory:

```
<?php

function buildSort(&$values) {
        return function ($a, $b) use(&$values) {
                if (!isset($values[$a])) {
                        $values[$a] = file_get_contents($a.'/file1.txt')*
                          file_get_contents($a.'/file2.txt');
                }
                if (!isset($values[$b])) {
                        $values[$b] = file_get_contents($b.'/file1.txt')*
                          file_get_contents($b.'/file2.txt');
                }

                return strcmp($values[$a], $values[$b]);
        };
}


$dirs = glob('*',GLOB_NOSORT|GLOB_ONLYDIR);
$values = array();
$sort = buildSort($values);

usort($dirs, $sort);
var_dump($dirs);
```

The answer that avoids passing $values by reference is left as an exercise for the reader. :)